# Navigationcontroller don't work fine

Tags: ios, uibutton, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have (hopefully) a little issue. The `rightCalloutAccessoryView` button method. I try to push the `navigationcontroller` to `another viewcontroller` but it dont work fine. I always get a Black screen. the `navigationBar` is disabled

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
// ... code ...
        pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [detailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetailView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        pinAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=detailButton;
// ... code ...
}
```

button:

```
-(IBAction)showDetailView:(UIButton *)sender
{
    InfoViewController *infoView = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:infoView animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"pushed Button!!!!!!");

}
```

My goal: `ViewController` press the `detailButton` and push to `InfoViewController`.

Maybe that was just a small mistake, which I do not find.

Comment: the init method, aren´t you using a xib file ? like -initWithNibName:bundle

Comment: i dont have any xib file because I'm using storyboard

Comment: But still if you do not tell what resource file to load, how will the sdk know what to load? you must give the name of the xib file in the initWithNib method. use InfoViewController *infoView = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil]; or use [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InfoViewController"];

Comment: both aren't work for me: `doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'InfoViewController'` and `Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle with name 'infoViewController'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your InfoViewController is in the storyboard, then you need to get that one, not make a new one with alloc init. The InfoViewController needs an identifier in the storyboard, then you can instantiate it like:

```
InfoViewController *infoView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InfoViewController"];
```